# Debugging Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

I'm deploying to a VPS using capistrano, based on the guide at RailsCasts. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast

It's failing on the **deploy:cold** command, with a conflict with Ruby. I actually can't see what the problem is, as when I shell into the same user the Ruby version looks correct.

```
$ cap shell
cap> which ruby
[establishing connection(s) to 192.xxx.xxx.xxx]
 ** [out :: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx] /home/deployer/.rbenv/shims/ruby
cap> ruby -v
** [out :: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

This is the error:

```
command finished in 655ms
* 2013-07-01 16:40:39 executing `bundle:install'
* executing "cd /home/deployer/rails/assay/releases/20130701144038 && bundle install --  gemfile /home/deployer/rails/assay/releases/20130701144038/Gemfile --path   /home/deployer/rails/assay/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
servers: ["192.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
[192.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
** [out :: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx] rbenv: version `1.9.3' is not installed
command finished in 662ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

My question is: **how can I debug this?** When I read the **deploy.rb** file I can't see where it even references the Ruby version. Pretty frustrating, I am about ready to ftp the repo up, which is not ideal obviously.

Comment: looks like you are using rbenv for your ruby install - you might want to checkout this post: http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2012/2/deploying-with-rbenv-and-capistrano/ - `set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had similar issue, the reason was `.ruby-version` file pointing at `1.9.3` (file was generated by rails-composer), while there was `1.9.3-p392` installed via rbenv on remote machine.

Comment: Actually I also used Rails Composer.

Answer (score 8):

Well I finally got to the bottom of the issue - a mismatch between ruby versions use by Capistrano and what was actually on the server.

To debug Capistrano run it like this:

```
cap deploy:cold  -d
```

That was you can step through the commands and access the temporary directories on the remote server before they are deleted.

Comment: This is no more true for Capistrano 3: `OptionParser::AmbiguousOption: ambiguous option: -d`

Comment: for Capistrano3 we can use `cap staging deploy -t` instead

Answer (score 0):

Debug info of capistrano can be shown by `tail -f log/capistrano.log`.

Comment: where to find that file ?